# Can't install kali and Windows 10 as dual boot. How can I fix this error?

Tags: kali-linux, dual-boot, grub

I tried to install Kali Linux and Windows 10 as dual boot but I'm facing a problem. I can't find a proper solution.

[I'm sure some of your must've faced this situation. How can I fix this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpKiw.jpg)

Comment: That's not too much text to re-type (https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/117549), and the title of the picture's link does not describe the picture.

Comment: Kali Linux is a highly specialized distribution intended for use by computer security professionals in the performance of their professional assignments. It is **not** intended for beginners; it is not intended to be used as a day-to-day operating system, either by beginners or by professionals. It is a special tool for use in specific situations.

Comment: "I'm a noob" - then don't touch Kali, Kali is for "professionals" not n00bs ... try Ubuntu, OpenSuse or Mint!

Answer (score 2):

Install [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and run Kali in a VM.

Also see this [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Answer (score -1):

KALI is not equipped to use UEFI BIOS and Win 10 must use UEFI. I use Kali under VM myself but you can try this fix [EFI Kali](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?271-How-to-EFI-install-Kali-Linux).

Comment: Kali fully supports UEFI.

Comment: I certainly didn't mean to jump the gun on that one. I've been using the older .ISO not the 2016.x or 2017.x. because of the removed programs. Should have not assumed it was same problem I had had.